# Change the style of numbers of the bookmarks

Tags: bookmarks

I want to know if there is a way of changing the style of the numbers of the bookmarks without changing the text. I want to place a dot after the roman number of the part bookmark and also I want to have the chapter bookmark numbers with no italic style.

[image]

Below, part of the code:

```
\makeatletter
\bookmarksetup{
addtohook={
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1
\bookmarksetup{bold}
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0
\bookmarksetup{italic}
\fi
}
}
\renewcommand{\Hy@numberline}[1]{#1.~}
\makeatother
```